# C++ LinkedList struct referenced as Double Pointer, and need to access Next Node

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

Okay, so I have a Linked List struct set up as so:

```
struct ListNode {
    ListNode* next;
    int data;
    ListNode(int in) {
        data = in;
        next = NULL;
    }
    ListNode(int in, ListNode* n) {
        data = in;
        next = n;
    }
};
```

Along with an insert function:

```
bool insertNode(ListNode **head, int position, int data) {
    if (position == 0) {
        ListNode *element = new ListNode(data, *head->next);
        *head->next = element;
        return true;
    }
    else if (head == NULL)
        return false;
    else {
        insertNode(head->next, position-1, data);
    }
}
```

How would I access the next element of head?  With the code that currently is in place, I get this error message:

```
request for member ‘next’ in ‘* head’, which is of non-class type ‘ListNode*’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
(*head)->next
```

EDIT: For more information about operator priority http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Success! Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Spoke too soon.  It works for the first two head->next calls, but when I pass it in to my recursive call, it doesn't like it: cannot convert ‘ListNode*’ to ‘ListNode**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘bool insertNode(ListNode**, int, int)’

Comment: And if you look at the operator priority, u should know why it works!

Comment: '&head->next' doesn't work.  It gives me the error message I originally had

Comment: Uffff ;) I'm tired. &(*head)->next

Comment: Okay, I found a solution:  
   `ListNode *nextHead = (*head)->next;  
    insertNode(&nextHead, position-1, data);`